# Find datatype, unique values and max values for all columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv which I have imported using the following script

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("filen__new.csv")
data.head()
```

I wish to know the type of each column (ie whether its numerical, boolean or any other type)
When I do `data.info()` I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 200009 entries, 0 to 200008
Columns: 151 entries, iterator to parse168
dtypes: float64(149), int64(1), object(1)
```

Is there a better way to get the type of each of the columns along with column name:
for eg  something that indicates my column 1  name is iterator and its type as numeric/float &
name of column2 is   parse1  and  its type is boolean

I also was looking to generate unique and max values of each of columns and use the code for each of my column names

```
## for unique values for each column
uniqueValues = data['iterator'].unique()
print('Unique elements in column "iterator" ')
print(uniqueValues)
###printing the max value of column1 
column1 = data["iterator"]
max_value = column1.max()
print(max_value)
```

If i have 150 columns I have to repeat this 150 times. is there a way i could do this better?

Answer (score 0):

For datatype do `df.dtypes` and it will show you all the columns types.

For all unique values in a column you can use `df.nunique()` to see how many there are and

```
for col in df:
    print(df[col].unique())
```

to print it out.

To find all max values you can use

```
for col in df:
    print(df[col].max())
```

to print out.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html), `pd.DataFrame.info()` truncates by default at `pd.options.display.max_info_columns`. This behavior could be changed with the argument `max_cols`. The default value for this is 100, as could be seen with:

```
print(pd.options.display.max_info_columns)
100
```

For a Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)

```
import pandas as pd


n_columns = 150
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[x for x in range(n_columns)], 
               data=[[x for x in range(n_columns)],
                     [x*100 for x in range(n_columns)]
                     ])
df1.info(max_cols=n_columns)

# You could access the types through
df1.dtypes

# You could access the column names through
df1.columns

# You could access the column max values as
df1.max()
```

A `pd.DataFrame` does not possess the `unique` method, only a `pd.Series`. So in order to avoid for loops, you could apply it to a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x.unique())
```

For new questions, perhaps you could follow this good practice guide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and for [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

At last, the Pandas documentation is very well explained, you could consult it for more details and several better examples.